# Pulling repository docker shows error image not found

Tags: docker

I tried pulling latest image and it shows image not found. Please help!

$ docker pull url.org/image-sample:latest

Pulling repository url.org/image-sample

Error: image image-sample:latest not found

Comment: I'm guessing `url.org` is not docker image repository.

Comment: @Grimmy, thank you I already figured it out. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. url.org is not a docker image.

Solution is to check the available images.